# Unable to successfully embed/display POWR.io Reviews

Tags: javascript

To anyone who comes across this question, hope this finds you well.

I've created a quick little test.html file and opening it up in Chrome. It includes the following snippet which I haven't been able to get to display anything.

```
<div class="powr-reviews" id="2753c372_1606181564"></div>
<script src="https://www.powr.io/powr.js?platform=html"></script>
```

It's supposed to embed/display this reviews page:

https://www.powr.io/reviews/i/26790199#page

Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is extremely hard to understand https://www.powr.io/powr.js?platform=html

that said, this is a quick but very raw way to load a page BUT the source must be the same(in this case: https://powr.io)

```js
var theFrame=document.createElement('iframe')
theFrame.src="https://www.powr.io/reviews/i/26790199#page"
document.body.appendChild(theFrame)



//document.appendChild isn't reliable since it says some ONLY ALLOWS ONE APPENDAGE or something like that
//the above code only works if cors doesn't block you, meaning that your source for this would be from powr.io as well(THIS IS A SANDBOX SO IT GETS BLOCKED BECAUSE OF ORIGIN DIFFERENCE)

//if i run the code below, it works on newtab(if u pop up the console paste and enter)
document.write('<div class="powr-reviews" id="2753c372_1606181564"></div>')
var x=document.createElement('script')
x.src="https://www.powr.io/powr.js?platform=html"
document.body.appendChild(x)
```

Now I have a small [repl](https://repl.it/join/tdgythzc-paultaylor2) to show that your 2 lines work, but IT DOESN'T WORK IF YOUR SOURCE(the origin when running it on client side) IS FILE

Now below, I run some attempts to imitate what on earth that code does

JavaScript Example and its [repl](https://repl.it/join/ufaccdhw-paultaylor2)

```js
//iframe loader
function iframer(sourceUrl){
  document.body.innerHTML="" //makes sure ONLY this loads
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.src = sourceUrl;
  iframe.width=screen.availWidth;
  iframe.height=screen.availHeight;
  iframe.style="border: solid transparent";
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  return iframe;
}
var myFrame=iframer("https://www.powr.io/reviews/i/26790199#page")
console.log(myFrame)
```

HTML Example and its [repl](https://repl.it/join/sugnkgos-paultaylor2)

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='https://www.powr.io/reviews/i/26790199#page'">
```

Comment: That worked, thanks.  I'm still curious as to what it is that platforms like ShowIt, Big Cartel, Wix, etc. are doing differently to enable them to embed the original couple lines of code I provided.

Comment: @NoelG. show one of these sites please.. i'll just scout around and see exactly.. but they either did what i did and used css to make it look fabulous, or took a picture of it and include the picture, OR on their backend they requested the page(backend not client end because CORS is crazy and lives on clients' browsers) and they just add the response text in the html content the server returns

Comment: but like i said.. client side wise(in case u don't control the backend), that's the only way.. css makes things look amazing

Comment: So like with ShowIt, their designer interface allows custom code to be pasted, as seen in this [screenshot](https://photos.app.goo.gl/ZX18kMiKgoDWQVRFA). I plug in the two lines from my original post and they are able to display https://www.powr.io/reviews/i/26790199#page  as seen [here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/94HLo3cxUjXL3tgP9), even though there is no direct reference to it in the code I pasted.

Comment: it works but only in `certain` circumstances.. like applying it to a new tab's console and running it works smoothly, trying to determing fully where and where it WON'T RUN

Comment: running it from file gives a strange error `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target origin 'null' in a call to 'postMessage'.`

Comment: once your client's source isn't `file` it works normally @NoelG. I'm now interested in the code as it seems to trick cors into loading something with a cross extension

Comment: Indeed very interesting that it doesn't work when source is File.  Tried out your repl, good stuff @TheBombSquad.  Thanks for all the research on this.  Keep me posted if you discover anything further.

Comment: a lot of `postMessage`s running, so im researching the method

Comment: @NoelG. i made some progress in being able to display to an extent what that huge javascript file was able to(they only work in the repls though)

Comment: ooh the js example i made works in file, just looking to make the border disappear, the html version works without that strange looking border but it redirects to the page itself(not sure if u want that)

Comment: ok I finally made a style in which the iframe border is invisible

Comment: Do you have an repl with the working example?  It works in File?  Thanks @TheBombSquad.

Comment: yea, i had `JavaScript and its repl` and that's the repl that doesnt redirect to the site but still loads it.. https://repl.it/join/ufaccdhw-paultaylor2

Comment: hi @TheBombSquad, script.js in that repl though references  https://www.powr.io/reviews/i/26790199#page  instead of doing the thing with  <div class="powr-reviews" id="2753c372_1606181564"></div><script src="https://www.powr.io/powr.js?platform=html"></script>

Comment: oh @NoelG. that's the obvious part.. that huge powr.io/powr.js?platform=html file I assume it is design to load several review pages and the info of the div will correspond to a specific review page(in this case, powr.io/reviews/i/26790199#page)

Comment: that might sound complex and all but i'll take in database terms.. think of the div as a primary key for the script to load the RIGHT review page

Comment: Makes sense @TheBombSquad.  Just to confirm, there's no way to do the div trick with source as File right?  Earlier in the thread we were saying it only works when client source isn't File.

Comment: @NoelG. the JavaScript Example works from any origin and so does the HTML example.. for the js example, https://repl.it/join/ufaccdhw-paultaylor2 i just made it fit in one file to show

Comment: Can't get this one to work @TheBombSquad...

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title>NVG Test</title></head><body><div class="powr-reviews" id="2753c372_1606181564"></div><script src="https://www.powr.io/powr.js?platform=html"></script></body></html>`

Comment: @NoelG. I now saw this but now I don't see the problem.. it works, whether i `document.write` that or I save it to an html file, it works **EXCEPT WHEN ORIGIN IS FILE**.. I said, already, the function `iframer` works, check https://repl.it/join/ufaccdhw-paultaylor2.. just for that function, the argument is the url of the reviews page

Comment: Great news @TheBombSquad, I finally got it to work by going through IIS.  What does IIS do that simply doing an "Open with Google Chrome" of my test.html from some random local directory doesn't?

Comment: iis will have user load from different source @NoelG. but i have several working examples of your question of loading the page through html/javascript the key example being https://repl.it/join/ufaccdhw-paultaylor2 so have i answered your question?

Comment: Definitely. I have ticked off the checkmark on the answer you provided. Thanks for all your efforts and insights.